# write 2 dataframes in 2 different excel sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I was trying something like this:

```
output_2df = pd.concat([installs, second_installs], ignore_index=True)
output_2df.to_excel('./installs.xlsx',sheet_name='Answers')

output_qdf = pd.concat([a_questionnaires, b_questionnaires], ignore_index=True)
output_qdf.to_excel('./installs.xlsx',sheet_name='questionnaires')
```

Although it works without an error, when I open my Excel file, I only see the second sheet. The data from the first dataframe seems to be overwritten.

Then I tried this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./installs.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# Append final dfs to one output_df

output_2df = pd.concat([installs, second_installs], ignore_index=True)
output_2df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Answers')


output_qdf = pd.concat([a_questionnaires, b_questionnaires], ignore_index=True)
output_qdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Questionnaires')
```

However, in this case when I open my Excel file manually, I get an error that it cannot be opened since the file type is invalid.

What's the correct way to write two different dataframes to 2 separate sheets in the same Excel file?

Comment: The two dataframes are independent will create new XLSX files with the sheetnames you specify. As you use the same file name, the second one will replace the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.ExcelWriter` for this:

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
clean_year_examens.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Examens jaar')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name2')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: just rewritten the above code with comments. could you please update?
```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 
# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1') # We can specify a sheet name when writing.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2') 
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save() # Save the Excel file.
```

Comment: ah, I was missing the ```writer.save()```!